# http request in android

Tags: android, httpresponse

I would like to know if we can pass a database table as http response object to android application? I am using a serverside mysql database and I can pass a string to the client side right now. So I concatenated each column with a special character in server side and extracted it in client side to transfer a single row. But in case of table it is not possible, as the table may have huge amount of data. Do any one know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you will use some kind of serialization to exchange data between your Android application and your server.

The two most used serialization formats are [**XML**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/XML) and [**JSON**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSON) *-- I generally prefer JSON, but it's a matter of personal choice, I suppose*.

You should be able to find JSON libraries in several languages, including the one you are using on your server, and JAVA *(for the android-side)*.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do isn't possible. You need to design your system so that the whole table isn't needed in the Android application. Instead, you can send a message with the number of rows found and perhaps their ids. Then, you would make individual http requests to retrieve the contents of each row on a when needed basis.